# jQuery Tools Overlay invokes vertical Scrollbar in IE

Tags: internet-explorer-8, scrollbar, overlay, jquery-tools

When i open a JQT Overlay with Internet Explorer 8 the first time, a vertical scrollbar appears in the main window. When i close the overlay and open it again, the scrollbar won't appear. How can i avoid the appearance of the vertical scrollbar when i open the overlay the first time?

Answer (score 1):

The only answer i have found so far to fix this problem in IE8 is to open up your JqueryUI css file, and find the `.ui-widget-overlay` selector and add the following rule :

```
position: fixed;
```

so effectively:

```
.ui-widget-overlay  { position: fixed; }
```